# Is it possible to update one value and delete another one by a single Cassandra CQL query?

Tags: cassandra, cql3

Given a table:

```
CREATE TABLE t (
    k text,
    v1 int,
    v2 int,
    PRIMARY KEY (k)
)
```

Is it possible to set `v1` to some value and delete (set to null) `v2` with a single query? Something like:

```
UPDATE t SET v1=100, v2=NULL WHERE k='somekey';
```

I have looked through the docs, but found nothing.

It would be a nice to have feature for two reasons:

- Updating a table with a lots of columns using prepared statements is really painful now.
- If my understanding is correct, row update by a single query should be atomic, whereas there are no guarantees for two consequent queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The query you suggested works (at least) in CQL3:

```
cqlsh:ks> UPDATE t SET v1=100, v2=NULL WHERE k='somekey';
cqlsh:ks> select * from t;

 k       | v1  | v2
---------+-----+------
 somekey | 100 | null
```

If you want to do more complicated atomic updates e.g. across different row keys or column families, you can wrap separate UPDATEs in `BEGIN BATCH`...`APPLY BATCH`.

Comment: Oops, it was a silly question. I've got stuck with NULLs in PreparedStatements and didn't even try this query in cqlsh. I guess, I  need to create another question. But thanks for your answer anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to updating to null, you might consider using the [DELETE operation](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/cql3/CQL.html#deleteStmt) if you just want to remove data, which works atomically on columns and/or rows.

You mentioned you could not find the documentation. Here is the documentation related to Richard's excellent answer:
 - Updates on a single row by a single query are [atomic by default](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/1.2/index.html?pagename=docs&version=1.2&file=index#cassandra/cql_reference/../dml/dml_about_transactions_c.html#concept_ds_by4_cvx_zj).
 - [Batch operations](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/1.2/index.html?pagename=docs&version=1.2&file=index#cassandra/cql_reference/batch_r.html) are also atomic since 1.2